# Convert List(of Class) to a String for storing in IsolatedStorage

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1

Okay, so in my Windows Phone App I have a few pieces of data that need to be stored in IsolatedStorage, but the caveat is that they also need to be encrypted to protect some personal information. So right now, I have the Class setup for creating the List (let's just say for example this is a list of clients) but now I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to convert the List to a String so I can encrypt it (the encryption method will take a string as an input) and then convert that string back to a List?

Here's an example of a class that I have

```
 Public Class ClientClass
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property createdDate As String
    Public Property contactID As String
    Public Property contactName As String
    Public Property investmentAmount As String
    Public Property currentStatus As String        
End Class
```

And so what I want to be able to do is take the List(Of ClientClass) that I have and convert  it into a single string that can then be encrypted for storage.

```
'pseudo code example of what I want
Dim clientString as String = ConvertListToString(clientList)

'then later when needed
Dim clientList As List(Of ClientClass) = ConvertStringToList(clientString)
```

Also, it doesn't have to be a string either if that's the problem, if there is any way I can either just story the List (I would need to figure out how to encrypt the list as a single object) or converting it something else then I'm all for it as well. Just can't seem to figure out where to go for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize the List to JSON string and encrypt the JSON string.

> List -> serialization -> decrypted string (JSON) ->
>   encryption -> encrypted string -> storage -> encrypted string ->
>   decryption -> decrypted string (JSON) -> deserialization ->
>   List

[Explore JSON.NET.](http://james.newtonking.com/json) It's simply the best.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. I did something similar for the Android app and using the JSON library but I just completely forgot about it until you posted this. Thanks.